# Trying to understand password_verify PHP

Tags: php, hash

I am trying to understand how password_verify work to use it for resetting the password.
I would've thought this would've worked, but the hashed don't seem to match?

```
$sUniqueCode = uniqid('1234', true);
$sHash1 = password_hash($sUniqueCode, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sHash2 = password_hash($sUniqueCode, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sHash3 = password_hash($sUniqueCode, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

echo "Hash 1: ".$sHash1."<br>";
echo "Hash 2: ".$sHash2."<br>";
echo "Hash 3: ".$sHash3."<br>";

if(password_verify($sHash1, $sHash1)) {
    echo "Hash 1 = hash 2 <br>";
}

if(password_verify($sHash3, $sHash1)) {
    echo "Hash 1 = hash 3";
}
```

I don't get an echo of the last two conditions, what am I missing here?

**Context**

Why I want to understand this is because I want to generate one hash of the same unique_id to be stored in the database, and 1 to be send in an email as GET-variable.

If the example above does not work, the comparison of the two hashes on my website will not validate to true either, right?

Comment: You are probably giving a wrong kind of argument, http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every hash generated using [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is salted with a different salt, so `$sHash1`, `$sHash2` and `$sHash3` will all be different

[password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is used to compare a plaintext password against a hashed password, not two hashes with each other; use password_verify() to compare `$sUniqueCode` with any of the hashes that you have generated

```
if (password_verify($sUniqueCode, $sHash1)) { ... }
```

**EDIT**

Rather than sending a password hash through email, which isn't useful in any way, send a nonce link for initial account access, or new password generation

Comment: Ah that explains a lot. But what exactly is a 'nonce link'?

Comment: For instance: Do I have to use my variable $sUniqueCode to send in the mail as GET-variable and then compare it with the hashed one in the databse?

Comment: You don't want to send a password, any password, in a plaintext email if you can possibly help it. A nonce would be a one-time time-limited link - have a read of [this OWASP article on password resets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Insufficient_Password_Recovery)

Comment: I dont send a password, this is a newly generated url specifically for one-time access. I am using the password_hash function because it is a better protection that e.g. md5. I would never send a password over email :)

Comment: Using password_hash/password_verify is not a practical approach to generating/validating a nonce; you really need to generate a hashed value that contains a timestamp that you can validate to ensure that it is time-limited

Comment: Aah oke, thank you for the explaination and the alternative:)